# MYSQL query and compare values if multiple rows found

Tags: mysql

Im not too mysql savvy and i'm having issues creating a select that fits with my needs.
I have a database table that looks similar to this:

```
registrar
id balance date
---------------------
1  500.00  2013-01-01
2  402.00  2013-01-01
3  396.00  2013-01-02
4  394.00  2013-01-02
```

I have a query that I use to pull the data into a script and display the data:

```
SELECT balance, date FROM $registrar WHERE date BETWEEN '$starting_date' AND '$ending_date'
```

However, it appears that when querying, mysql is only returning the newest entry for that date. Id like if possible to return the lower balance amount of that date if found multiple rows matching the date criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

```
SELECT balance, date FROM $registrar WHERE date BETWEEN '$starting_date' AND '$ending_date' ORDER BY balance DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use order by class in the end of query

```
SELECT balance, date FROM $registrar WHERE date BETWEEN '$starting_date' AND '$ending_date' ORDER BY balance DESC
```

By default it id , so u have to put balance .